# Problems posting notifications from bash script started from cron (KDE)

Tags: bash, kubuntu, kde, cron, notification

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 Focal (KDE Plasma v5.18.5, KDE Frameworks v5.68.0, Qt v5.12.8) and I have a bunch of Bash scripts that are expected to post some notifications, to the user and this is the step I am currently having unresolved issues with. To post notifications I am using `notify-send` (from `libnotify-bin` package) and `kdialog` (from `kdialog` package). The [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for my case can look like this (say, it's `/tmp/test.sh`, executable file):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

notify-send "notify-send test"
kdialog --passivepopup 'kdialog test' 5
```

When you run this script manually, it works just fine and produces what you expect - shows the notification that appears on your destkop. In my case it's expected to show up in bottom-left corner of the screen as I do have vertical panel on the left edge:

[image: Expected results]

However when I try to run my scripts from a cron job, with crontab entry like this:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /tmp/test.sh
```

`notify-send` fails completely (shows nothing) and `kdialog` shows something oddly themed and misplaced (in top-left part of the screen):

[image: kdialog popup]

The cron job is running on behalf of my user and I am logged during the tests. When checking syslog I see:

```
Sep 10 20:05:01 HOST CRON[159928]: (USER) CMD (DISPLAY=:0 /tmp/test.sh)
Sep 10 20:05:15 HOST org.freedesktop.Notifications[159641]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Sep 10 20:05:15 HOST dbus-daemon[76746]: [session uid=1000 pid=76744] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Sep 10 20:05:15 HOST dbus-daemon[76746]: [session uid=1000 pid=76744] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.497' (uid=1000 pid=159930 comm="notify-send notify-send test " label="unconfined")
```

I was searching for `org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout` but failed to find any explanation what this is really caused by. I suspect that cron job environment is missing something (i.e. say env var?) that is otherwise present when launched from interactive shell, but I somehow stuck and not sure what to check next. So, ancient, posts suggested turning off panel auto-hide (I am no using auto-hide feature) or ensuring I did not mute notifications in tray (not my case either). I definitely lacks some knowledge here, so my question is - what is really preventing notification from showing up as expected? I understand that running cron job is not an equivalent of user's manual launch, yet I failed to figure out what is really the vital difference here that I should artificially provide. What shall I peek next in my finding culprit quest? I am simply out of ideas at the moment, and nothing I found during my search crusade pushed mu any step forward right now.

I'd really apreciate any hints or thoughts about that or what to peek/read/investigate next as I am currently out of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen other people been successful setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` or `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

I had a try locally and these works fine here.

```bsh
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus /tmp/test.sh
```

or

```bsh
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) /tmp/test.sh
```

Comment: Funny thing is that my real scripts are checking and setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` but apparently I got this implemented incorrectly. At least I know where to investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. The approach with `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)` worked for me on Kubuntu 23.10 for a script leveraging `kdialog` and `cvlc`!